# Some photos are darker than other consecutive photos

Tags: nikon, exposure

I have a 6 years old Nikon D750 and Sigma 105mm 2.8 lens.

Recently when I take several photos of an object with exactly the same settings the first photo (and sometimes one or two more) is darker that the next ones (that have correct exposure).

Is there a problem with the camera or the lens?

Comment: Could be the lighting. What lighting are you using & precisely what settings on the camera?

Comment: How much darker? Less than a stop, or more than a few stops... ?

Answer (score 1):

I think my camera has a setting where each time you take a photo it changes some settings (aperature, shutter speed, ISO) so maybe yours does too?

Comment: I think you're referring to bracketing, and that would result in all photos in the sequence having a different brightness.

Comment: @wilkgr yeah that sounds right

Comment: Bracketing is not set and no setting was changed. Now the camera works properly. Is there any maintenance that should be done except cleaning the senor from time to time? I assume that it is better not to touch/tune anything. The photo is here: https://www.pomage.com/2021/06/mothers-purse-and-wallet.html ,

Comment: @David sounds like a fault in the aperture mechanism on a lens where the aperture default is stopped down when off the camera. With a mechanical aperture linkage this would be a mechanical issue. With a lens with electronic aperture control it might be a dirty contact.